# asp.net:how to change Hosted URL into sub URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, localhost, hosted

Question is how I change my URL into Sub URL like if I have

http://www.abc.xyz.com
then I want to give option to the user that they will change their login URL like.....
http://www.123.xyz.com

first URL Adds user and ask about the new URL which will be dedicated only for the particular user and this will follow for all the users

is there any possibility to solve this in ASP.net (VB.NET or C#)

Comment: try to use url rewriting of asp.net may be u get some clue from it

Comment: yess i need to know about asp.net URL rewriting

Comment: Use google for getting knowledge of  things..Here is a good artical
[Url rewriting](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/641758/An-Example-of-URL-Rewriting-With-ASP-NET)